# How do we solve this two variable equation (involving periodic functions)?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods

Is there a way to solve these sort of two variable system of equations:

$$x^2((\sin(Ax))^2+(\sin(Bx))^2) + My((\sin(Cy))^2+(\sin(Dy))^2) - E=0$$

where $A, B, C, D, E, M \in \mathbb{R}$. I could not find anything regarding equations (involving periodic functions) like this. Can someone please comment?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I am sorry but the equation was possibly incorrect. the sin terms are of the form: $$(sin(Ax))^2$$ or $$(sin(Ax)*sin(Ax))$$ and so on.. If possible can you please help with this one and elaborate ??

Comment: If $w=Bx$, then $x=w/B$, so $x^2(\sin^2(Ax)+\sin^2(Bx))=(w/B)^2(\sin^2(A/B w)+\sin^2(w))=E-y^2(\sin^2(Cy)+\sin^2(Dy))$ where $\sin^2(x)=\sin(x)\sin(x)$. Then multiply both sides by $B^2$ to get $w^2(\sin^2(A/B w)+\sin^2(w))=B^2 E-B^2 y^2(\sin^2(Cy)+\sin^2(Dy))$ and solve for $x$. If you mean the edit from $sin$ to sin, then `\sin` is usually used to look more neat. Feel free to change it

Comment: I understand upto this point: $$w^2(\sin^2(A/B w)+\sin^2(w))=B^2 E-B^2 y^2(\sin^2(Cy)+\sin^2(Dy))$$ but there are 2 variables here w and y. How do I solve from this equation is what i am struggling with? P.S. I will edit in a bit..

Comment: Nothing about the solution is periodic.

Comment: Sorry. It should have said involving periodic functions.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Can you please clarify? I am struggling to see how variable change can help solve this?

Comment: @xyz It just simplifies the equation a bit.

Comment: sure but I don't see how it helps solve?

Comment: can anyone please help?